# How do you make an application "Open" for TestComplete

Tags: testcomplete

How do you make an application "Open" for TestComplete.
How would you send a string to the TestComplete log? What about an Image.
Describe the levels of visibility of an application under test to TestComplete

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! For future reference, please don't ask multiple unrelated questions in a single post. It would be better if you posted the part about logging as a separate question. Sticking to one question per post helps keep things simple and makes it easier for others to find answers.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all types of applications are "Open" for TestComplete without any special preparations. Even if some preparations are required, all of them are described in detail in [the really great product documentation](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/28563/). In a common case, TestComplete can "see" almost all internal visual and even non-visual objects with their native properties and methods.

As for sending a message or an image to the Test Log - you need to make use of the corresponding method of the Log object: [Log.Message](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/33325/) or [Log.Picture](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/32862/).

Answer (score 0):

Look out for the plugins available if your application is not natively "Open" to access the objects.